# How to write "not in ()" sql query using join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, notin

Could some one please provide how to write following sql query using joins. I do not want use **not in** as well as if possible I would like to replace **where** condition as well.

```
SELECT d1.Short_Code
FROM domain1 d1
WHERE d1.Short_Code NOT IN (
  SELECT d2.Short_Code
  FROM Domain2 d2
)
```

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This article:

- [**NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

may be if interest to you.

In a couple of words, this query:

```
SELECT  d1.short_code
FROM    domain1 d1
LEFT JOIN
        domain2 d2
ON      d2.short_code = d1.short_code
WHERE   d2.short_code IS NULL
```

will work but it is less efficient than a `NOT NULL` (or `NOT EXISTS`) construct.

You can also use this:

```
SELECT  short_code
FROM    domain1
EXCEPT
SELECT  short_code
FROM    domain2
```

This is using neither `NOT IN` nor `WHERE` (and even no joins!), but this will remove all duplicates on `domain1.short_code` if any.

Comment: @Quassnoi, could you please provide the efficient way way writing the same query using  either "NOT NULL" and/or "NOT EXISTS"

Comment: @Elan: your original query is just nice. Just create the indexes on `short_code` in both tables.

Comment: @Quassnoi - You are assuming he doesn't need any information from the domain2 table

Comment: @Aducci: I'm assuming nothing, I'm just rewriting the original query.

Comment: @Quassnoi - You say it is less efficient.

Comment: @Aducci: `LEFT JOIN` is less efficient indeed. The question was "how to rewrite without `NOT IN`" — here's how.

Comment: DUDE you are SUPER AWESOME :) Thanks for the above query i was stuck somewhere like hell and You are a SAVIOR :)

Comment: @VinayChopra: my pleasure, but my query was supposed to be less efficient :)

Comment: well m not much experienced in this field , so i  can't judge .Well i like your attitude , genrally people feels proud after getting knowledge and you are Down to Earth :) . Hmm thanks :)

Comment: According to [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/22/sql-server-better-performance-left-join-or-not-in/)  link AVOID to use is null with left join. Better use not in.

Comment: @kostasch. That's what's written in the answer

Comment: @Quassnoi i am sorry. you are right. I didn't noticed. :)

Comment: @Quassnoi Shouldn't "will work but it is less efficient than a NOT NULL (or NOT EXISTS) construct" be "will work but it is less efficient than a NOT **IN** (or NOT EXISTS) construct."?

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT d1.Short_Code 
FROM domain1 d1
LEFT JOIN domain2 d2
ON d1.Short_Code = d2.Short_Code
WHERE d2.Short_Code IS NULL
```

Answer (score 8):

I would opt for `NOT EXISTS` in this case.

```
SELECT D1.ShortCode
FROM Domain1 D1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 'X'
     FROM Domain2 D2
     WHERE D2.ShortCode = D1.ShortCode
    )
```

Comment: What difference would `NOT EXISTS` make?

Comment: Instead of an outer join or a complex OR operation (with the NOT IN clause) the optimizer should use the equivalent of an exclusion merge join between the two tables.

Comment: the optimizer will build exactly same plan for both `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` (as long as `short_code` is not nullable). There will be no "complex OR operations".

Comment: Didn't realize that. Behavior in Teradata is slightly different.